# Hide placeholder after the first entry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this AngularJS code which allows user to add multiple tags.

```
<tags-input min-length="1" add-on-comma="true" add-on-enter="true"  ng-model="modalData.tech" placeholder="Add Tags" display-property="tech">
    <auto-complete source="loadAutoComplete('tech', {value:$query}) | filter : $query"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

I would like to hide the placeholder once the user adds at least 1 tag. How should I do this? A code example would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is *conceptual*, and may not work out of the box.  There's too many questions about how your code works, and can't reasonably set up in a jsFiddle.

Basically, define an angular expression inside your `placeholder` attribute that will evaluate against the number of tags that have been assigned.

This depends on your expected value of `modalData.tech`, so may need adjusting.

```
placeholder="{{modalData.tech.length ? '' : 'Add tags'}}"
```

In context, this would look like so:

```
<tags-input min-length="1" add-on-comma="true" add-on-enter="true"  ng-model="modalData.tech" placeholder="{{modalData.tech.length ? '' : 'Add tags'}}" display-property="tech">
    <auto-complete source="loadAutoComplete('tech', {value:$query}) | filter : $query"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Why didn't I think of this!! Thank you so much :)